# Support technique pour CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

Bonjour,
nous cherchons un prestataire expérimenté qui pourrait nous aider à finir de configurer CiviCRM (cron, wkhtmltopdf, multi-sites,...).
Si cela est votre champ de compétence, vous pouvez me solliciter sur guillaume.sorel at all-in-group.fr.
Merci

Comment: Welcome to the SE forum! Just a little note: Since this forum is mainly an English speaking community, you might increase your chances for helpful responses by providing an English translation of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour!

CiviCRM en Francais:

- https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_1=All&services=All&language=fr&cms=All
- https://www.civicrmfr.org/